# 'System.TypeInitializationException' occured in ZeroMQ.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, zeromq

[image: Click here to see Code Picture]

I am able to successfully run the exact same code using "Console Application" in VS 2015. However, when I try to run the same code using "ASP.NET Web Application" it throws an exception error saying:

'System.TypeInitializationException' in ZeroMQ.dll("The type initializer for 'ZeroMQ.lib.zmq' threw an exception.")

Someone had a similar issue [to this one here](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4/issues/19)(I am not sure if he/she was using Console Application though), and people suggested setting the files in i386 and amd64 to "copy if newer."

My question is:
**Why is it throwing an exception when I use ASP.NET Web Application but not when I use Console Application? 
How do I get ZMQ to run in ASP.NET Web Application?**

Thanks so much for your help!

FYI: The code is supposed to be sending data to Python Server and receive the result that Python Server sends back to c#.

Comment: Is the problem happening in your development environment or only when you publish it on a server? Maybe you should try to run VS with admin privileges to see if it still happens. Have you tried changing the target processor?

Comment: I tried running VS with admin privileges, but it throws the same exception. My target platform is on "Any CPU" right now. Now I am thinking about using rabbitmq instead of zmq and seeing if it works. Please let me know if you have more suggestions and thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You probably using 64bit dll of zeromq instead of 32bit. Anyway I recommend to NetMQ when using zeromq within C#. Exactly for that reason. NetMQ is native port of zeromq to C#. https://github.com/zeromq/netmq

Comment: @somdoron I actually tried using NetMQ yesterday, but it didn't work either. I will try again though... Quick question... Is there a library for NetMQ in python? Or can I use ZMQ library on python and NetMQ on c# and they will communicate fine?

Comment: @somdoron When I try using NetMQ, I get an error saying "'System.IO.FileLoadException' in NetMQ.dll ("Could not load file or assembly 'AsyncIO, Version=0.1.20.0...").

Comment: Thanks to somdoron, I was able to get it to work when I installed the NetMQ beta version instead.

Comment: It seems there is  a bug with latest stable version, I will fix it.

Comment: @Qualcom v3.3.3.3 is on nuget and works

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if you solved your problem.

I encountered the same problem on a Windows Server 2012 R2 and the solution was, to install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64). After that it works fine.

Comment: I had the x86 package installed, but I needed the x64 package.  This stopped me from pulling my hair out.  Thanks

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try, remove reference and add it back